# bootstrap.css: .container:before display table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In **bootstrap.css**

you can find either from Github  or from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#

Why does it use:

```
.container:before, .container:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
  zoom: 1;
  }

  .row:before, .row:after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
   zoom: 1;
   }
```

Why define display:table in .container:before/after and .row:before/after?

Answer (score 62):

http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

> The **clearfix hack** is a popular way **to contain floats** without resorting
>   to using presentational markup. This article presents an update to the
>   clearfix method that further reduces the amount of CSS required.

http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/The-style/#clearfix:

> Adding `.clearfix` to an element will ensure that it always fully
>   contains its floated children. There have been many variants of the
>   clearfix hack over the years, and there are other hacks that can also
>   help you to contain floated children, but the H5BP currently provides
>   this micro clearfix helper class.
>
> - `.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }`
>     This rule is understood by all browsers except for IE6/7. It generates
>     a pseudo-element before and after the content of the element that
>     contains floats. Setting `display: table` creates an anonymous
>     `table-cell` and a new block formatting context. This acts to prevent
>     top-margin collapse and improve the consistency between modern
>     browsers and IE6/7.
> - `.clearfix:after { clear: both; }`
>     Makes the `:after` pseudo-element clear the floated children of this element,
>     thereby making the element expand to contain the floats.
> - `.clearfix { zoom: 1; }`
>     Create new block formatting context in IE6/7 by triggering `hasLayout`