# micro clearfix doesn't work

Tags: html, css, layout, clearfix

i am using nicolas gallagher's micro-clearfix in my Fixed layout. And in my layout the green colored footer does not appear. Which means the clearfix doesn't work properly

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="al">
    </aside>
    <section class="content">

    </section>
    <aside class="ar">
    </aside>
    <footer class="cf">
    </footer>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.al {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
}
.ar {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
}
footer {
    background: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: green;
}
```

and micro clearfix

```
.cf:after, .cf:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table; 
}
.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4NJ6v/1/)

What am i doing wrong. how do i make this work. could someone help me please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You usually apply clearfix to the element that contains all of your floats.

However, in this case the easiest solution is to not use clearfix at all to contain the floats, but instead to use `clear: both` on `footer`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4NJ6v/3/

If you really wanted to use clearfix here, it would look like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/4NJ6v/6/

As you can see, an extra wrapping `div` had to be added, which isn't great.

Comment: i added cf to the footer but it still not work.  could you please tell me why is that. http://jsfiddle.net/4NJ6v/5/ i need to learn it :) i will use clear: both on footer.it is easier thanks

Comment: I just edited my answer with an example of how you would use clearfix in this situation. In your demo, you still have clearfix on the footer, which is simply not how you use it. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933494/bootstrap-css-containerbefore-display-table/8933894#8933894

Comment: That's it: a clearfix contains floated elements (and can have a visible background otherwise it'd have a null height thus no visible background) while `.clear { clear: both}` comes after floats if needed

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear:both` to footer http://jsfiddle.net/4NJ6v/4/ or you can add `float:left` to footer