# Why is there content: " " after and before many classes in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap.css they have added the following style rules after many classes,

```
display: table;
content: " ";
```

The classes that include this are:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.dl-horizontal dd:before,
.dl-horizontal dd:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after,
.form-horizontal .form-group:before,
.form-horizontal .form-group:after,
.btn-toolbar:before,
.btn-toolbar:after,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:before,
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group:after,
.nav:before,
.nav:after,
.navbar:before,
.navbar:after,
.navbar-header:before,
.navbar-header:after,
.navbar-collapse:before,
.navbar-collapse:after,
.pager:before,
.pager:after,
.panel-body:before,
.panel-body:after,
.modal-header:before,
.modal-header:after,
.modal-footer:before,
.modal-footer:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}
```

My question is why is this blankspace added after and before these classes and why is it's display set to table not something else like `display: block` or `display: inline-block`?

Comment: It's a clearfix method for clearing floats.

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: If think the answer previously posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8933894/2030321) will answer your question.

Comment: But with clearfix hack we have to set `visibility: hidden`,  `height: 0` and `display: block`.