# Flexbox children in Safari wider than supposed to be

Tags: safari, flexbox, width, grid-layout

See this pen:
https://codepen.io/armandsdz/pen/xqGaoe

I have a simple Foundation grid and I set `display:flex` to "row" element in order to get all columns be the same height.
It all works fine in Chrome, Firefox.
But on Safari, Edge, Yandex browsers (any version) those columns are a pixel or so too wide and it results in them not fitting within one row. Therefore, it wraps to two rows.
[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPomV.png)

Setting `flex-wrap: nowrap` would be an option in case of only one line but it's often not the case.
And most importantly it doesn't solve the issue at its core.

What am I missing in this flexbox world or is it a bug?

Thanks!

Addition: It happens not only when column width is, for example, 33.33333% but also when it's 25%. So where does that extra pixel come from?

Comment: Safari accounts for the width of the psudo elements (:before, :after), which Foundation and Bootstrap both generate on the .row-container. A simple solution is to set up a class name that removes those pseudo elements on the .row-container. E.g., 
.flex-container:before,
.flex-container:after {
  content: none;
}

Then put that on the .row-container (<div class="row flex-container").

Comment: Thanks!
So great to finally solve this mystery :)

I figured this only happens if `display:table` is set to :before,:after element.

What about setting `width:100%` on pseudo elements in order not to loose clearfix properties of this approch?
Then pseudo elements would be 100% in width and 0 in height. Therefore, they would not mess with actual columns but clearfix would still be in effect.

Comment: You don't need clearfix as flexbox disregards the floats altogether.

Comment: Great!
Thanks! Good to know!

Comment: You're welcome. Happy coding.

Comment: @DannieVinther The benefit to keeping the floats and clearfix would be for compatibility with older browsers that don't support flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

The `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements are part of a clearfix hack to contain floats and prevent margin collapse. (See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933494/bootstrap-css-containerbefore-display-table) about that.) Flexbox essentially disregards floats, but older browsers that don't support flexbox would fall back to using the floats so they would need the clearfix. Based on @DannieVinther and @Armands' comments, there are two possible solutions:

1. If you want to maintain the clearfix functionality for older browsers that don't support flexbox, you can add a rule to set `width: 100%;` on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. This will give the pseudo-elements a width of 100% and a height of 0, so they won't mess with the width of the rows of actual content.

   ```
   .row:before, .row:after {
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. If you don't need/care to support older browsers, you can simply override the clearfix hack by adding a rule to set `content: none;` on the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements.

   ```
   .row:before, .row:after {
       content: none;
   }
   ```