# Enable margin collapsing on rows and containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

After researching a bit, I found out that the pseudo elements added by Bootstrap are used for clearfix. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933894/3130281).

However, they also disrupt margin collapsing, which is something I often utilize. **How could I revert that?** Upon digging around in Bootstrap’s CSS, I found this:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

Why do **all** of these selectors have the clearfix hack **all** the time?

I use floats around one or two times per project, average, and it’s for some very small details. If I needed to float a `.container`, I would rather have the `clearfix` class *in addition* to `container`, instead of `container` being auto-clearfixed. The reason is - `container` could have collapsing margins, which I want; and `container clearfix` could provide clearfix *when needed*.

**Why do `container`, `container-fluid` and `row` use clearfix *by default*?** There’s already a `clearfix` utility class for when you need clearfix. Why force it automatically?
If I change the pseudo elements’ `display` from `table` to `block`, there’s no difference in my whole layout (on every screen size), apart from the collapsing margins.

**How could I prevent clearfix on the aforementioned classes?** Is manually deleting the CSS from `bootstrap.css` my best option?

**Edit:**
According to [Micro Clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) by Nicolas Gallagher:

> The use of `table` rather than `block` is only necessary if using `:before` to contain the top-margins of child elements.

So if I add something like this:

```
.container:before,
.container:after,
.container-fluid:before,
.container-fluid:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
    display: block;
}
```

after the Bootstrap CSS, would I get margin collapsing without any nasty side effects?

Comment: Simply put, it's really **not** easy to build a framework that works cross-browser cross-device and has as much flexibility as Bootstrap has. Giving up margin collapsing was one of the trade-offs. I wouldn't go modify core bootstrap CSS. If you do, you'll most likely break it on some device, in some browser. You're better off not using default Bootstrap classes where you need margin collapsing, but your own, custom classes.

Comment: Valid point, although I think it wouldn't harmful to tweak it. Take a look at my edit. Also, I want to utilize margin collapsing basically everywhere I have a `container` with `row`. If I add my own classes, I might as well use a different grid system, or no system at all.

Comment: More than what I said, which really, is common sense, I don't know. Bootstrap is effectively coded by 2 guys. They do take contributions, but nothing gets added without them thoroughly looking over it so you can safely say they are the authors. **I believe they are the only ones who can answer your question.** On the other hand, if your mods don't break in the browsers/devices you want, you're good to go. I still would place them in a different CSS file loaded after Bootstrap, though. At least you can do minor updates to Bootstrap this way.